# rbenv on CentOS: make: *** [exts.mk] Killed , after configuring openssl

Tags: ruby, openssl, centos, rbenv

I'm trying to build Ruby 2.1.5 with rbenv (ruby-build) on CentOS 6.4.

I already installed:

- openssl-devel
- libyaml-devel
- libffi-devel
- readline-devel
- zlib-devel
- gdbm-devel
- ncurses-devel

But I always get an error after cofiguring openssl:

```
$ rbenv install -v 2.1.5
...
configuring openssl
make: *** [exts.mk] Killed

BUILD FAILED (CentOS release 6.4 (Final) using ruby-build 20141225)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20150216195325.25931
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150216195325.25931.log

Last 10 log lines:
configuring io/wait
configuring json
configuring json/generator
configuring json/parser
configuring mathn/complex
configuring mathn/rational
configuring nkf
configuring objspace
configuring openssl
make: *** [exts.mk] Killed
```

Do you have ideas to solve it?

Comment: In addition, this is hosted on AWS t1.micro.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it installing:

```
yum -y install libffi-devel
```

Then you can proceed installing ruby.

```
rbenv install 2.2.0  
rbenv global 2.2.0
ruby -v
```

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/690#issuecomment-68113987).